# Capturing currently playing sound inside of browser

Tags: java, javascript, silverlight, html, actionscript

**Situation:**
I have a website running and I'd like to capture currently playing sound form user's sound card and make some visualizations with it.
I want to visualize what my client is listening right now.
**What I'd like to use:**
Flash, HTML5 and JavaScript. **No Java or Silverlight** but if your situation is only in those, please write it here, I want to know all possibilities.
**Question:**
Is it even possible? if yes, how? if no, the reason please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. None of the browser technologies you've mentioned have the ability to do that.

Flash can capture sound *input* (e.g, from a microphone), but it can't listen to system sound output.

Comment: Let me put this in perspective: It's not even *possible* to capture sound output on many platforms without installing drivers and/or changing the sound card configuration.

Comment: But I remember that we could intercept default sound card's output in C++, So I think it's possible but it's not achievable easily.